# New Array List to Return Specified Items from another Array List Using User Input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So my objective is to return an array list that specifies movies from the database array list when a user inputs the type of movie they are interested in. I assume that I needed to set the category from the user input, so I created a new object in order to do so. Where i am stuck is coming up with a code block for the new array list (in the MovieDB class) of specified movie category. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Main

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListMoviesApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Movie List App!");
    System.out.println("There are 100 movies in the list");

    String title = null;
    String category = null;

    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

    System.out.println("What genre are you interested in?");
    Movie newMovie = new Movie(title,category);
    category = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    newMovie.setCategory(category);

    System.out.println(MovieDB.getMovies(category));

    System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (y/n)");
    choice = sc.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Thanks for using the Movies List App! Goodbye!");
sc.close();
}
}
```

Movie

```
public class Movie {

private String title;
private String category;

public Movie(String title, String category) {
    this.title = title;
    this.category = category;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
}
```

MovieDB

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MovieDB {

private static ArrayList<Movie> allMovies = new ArrayList<>(12);

public static ArrayList<Movie> getAllMovies() {
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Citizen Kane", "drama"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Casablanca", "drama"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("The Wizard Of Oz", "musical"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Singin' In The Rain", "musical"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Star Wars", "scifi"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("2001: A Space Odyssey", "scifi"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Psycho", "horror"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("King Kong", "horror"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Annie Hall", "comedy"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("M*A*S*H", "comedy"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Lion King", "animated"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Fantasia", "animated"));

    return allMovies;
}

public static ArrayList<Movie> getMovies(String category) {
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    // Here I need code to return only movies from a specific category
    // From input from the user in the main

    return movies;
}    
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried looping over your list yet. Please do and [edit] your question when you run into any issues with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to loop allMovies and find out the movies which category is equal to the input. For example:

```
public class MovieDB {

private static ArrayList<Movie> allMovies = new ArrayList<>(12);

public static ArrayList<Movie> getAllMovies() {
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Citizen Kane", "drama"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Casablanca", "drama"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("The Wizard Of Oz", "musical"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Singin' In The Rain", "musical"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Star Wars", "scifi"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("2001: A Space Odyssey", "scifi"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Psycho", "horror"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("King Kong", "horror"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Annie Hall", "comedy"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("M*A*S*H", "comedy"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Lion King", "animated"));
    allMovies.add(new Movie("Fantasia", "animated"));

    return allMovies;
}

public static ArrayList<Movie> getMovies(String category) {
    if (allMovies.isEmpty()) {
        // Lazy initialize allMovies
        getAllMovies();
    }

    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    // Here I need code to return only movies from a specific category
    // From input from the user in the main
    if (category == null) {
        return movies;
    }

    for (Movie movie : allMovies) {
        if (movie.getCategory().equals(category)) {
            movies.add(movie);
        }
    }

    return movies;
}
}
```

UPDATE: You can not print the `ArrayList` like 
`System.out.println(MovieDB.getMovies(category));`

After you overrided the `toString()` method for Movie class, you can print the ArrayList as:

```
for (Movie movie : MovieDB.getMovies(category)) {
    System.out.println(movie);
}
```

instead of `System.out.println(MovieDB.getMovies(category));`.

Comment: So that only outputs "[]"......Should I assume that I need to getCategory from the Movie class for this to work?

EDIT: That code block already uses getCategory from the MOvie class....so im not sure whats missing?

Comment: You only need to make sure the getAllMovies() is called before look up the category in allMovies.

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, so I used an override toString in the Movie class (added below). Now Im getting the right content, but the output formatting is not what I expected:

output for scifi:
    [Star Wars, 2001: A Space Odyssey]
desired output for scifi:
    no brackets or comma, and listed vertically